# Add link from Area51 to Area51 discussion

Tags: support, area-51

At the moment if I am at [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) and I want to go to [Area 51 discussion](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/), I can't see any clear link. I think all the other sites (including Betas) have a **meta** link.

Is there any link to Area 51 discussion? If so, can it be made clearer? If not, can it be added?

At the moment my workaround is to go to a propsal, click on **create new discussion** and then click on the **Discussion Zone** link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a link:

[image: Area 51 discussion link]

between "chat" and "faq" just above the flying saucer.

Comment: thanks Chris - don't I feel an idiot now...? =:-)

Comment: @Wikis - we all miss the obvious from time to time.